# .htaccess is not working in wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, wamp

Below is my .htaccess file which is not working locally(wamp)..

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}$ search.php?hash=$1

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index($|\ |\?)
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

    ErrorDocument 404 /pivr/error.php

    <Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </Files>
```

Apache Error log says..

```
[Wed Aug 17 21:00:33.766183 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5780:tid 900] [client      ::1:50180] C:/wamp/www/search/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine',     perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I keep getting `500 internal Server error` how to fix it?

Comment: Look at your apahce error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed by activating rewrite engine in apache module ...